# fstream fails to open file

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a very weird problem. The setup is the following:

Library A uses Library B

Both libraries are installed as shared library independently and A links to B using CMake packages.

When I create an executable that directly links to B, everything works fine.
When I create an executable that links to A however, which is using B, then for some reason my fstream in B fails to open a specific file. I am 100% certain the file exists, is not requiring authorization and is not currently used. The error thrown by strerror(errno) is "No such file or directory".

I really have no clue what might go wrong. This is the code snippet I use for opening:

```
ifstream f;
f.open(filename.c_str(), ios_base::in|ios::binary);
if (f.fail()) {
    std::cout << "Opening Vocabulary failed: " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

I triple checked the path in filename is correct. These are the last resorts I can think of:

- Maybe Library A uses another C++ Standard as B, which is why the call to fstream fails?
- Maybe filename string is somehow corrupted, even though the path seems to be correct?
- Maybe some memory leak corrupts my c_str() command?

Is there anything else that I could check?

Edit: Ah, one thing I forgot: The fstream command is in a templated function in a header file. Maybe this has something to do with it?

Edit2: Here is the stack trace. "ORBVoc.bin" is the file I wanted to open. The only information I get out of this is, it does not exist...though it does exist.

https://www.file-upload.net/download-14359408/strace.log.html

Comment: Does `std::cout << filename` print the correct filename inside `if (f.fail())`? What is `filename`? How is it passed?

Comment: If it's under linux, run the executable under `strace` and see what really happens.

Comment: @Evg: filename prints the correct and absolute path. Filename is a std::string and is passed by const &.

Comment: @KamilCuk: I will try that, thanks! It is indeed under linux

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @KamilCuk I attached the strace.log. The only information that I get out of it, that the file does not exist...though it does exist.

Comment: So, well, nothing we can help you. Your kernel says you that the file does not exists yet you say it does - I would trust your kernel. Could be your process doesn't have permission to access any of the directories or the file. Or the file doesn't exists.

Comment: @KamilCuk There was indeed nothing you could help me with. Today everything literally is working magically. I guess the reboot did it? Maybe some messed up user permissions? I really have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently a reboot was all it takes. Today everything works flawlessly. No permissions, file or line of code was changed. I assume either something went terribly wrong, when my Laptop came back from hibernation. Or it was some pending ubuntu update? I really have no idea. I could swear it was shutdown at least once the past 2-3 days. But jeah, I have no other explanation. Maybe someone smarter can answer this with his glass ball...

Anyway, thanks for the answers, appreciate it! At least I learned about strace $:^)